# Xamarin Android: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException launching second Activity

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I just started development for Android in C# using Xamarin and VisualStudio 2017. Quite a different paradigm from Windows eco-system.. Target is a business app, that will have a specific audience, but before i get deep into that i'm just trying to learn the ropes, understand concepts & procedures..

Therefore, i start with simplest app, using Blank template.  That results in creating a project with an activity (MainActivity.cs), and 2 resources (Resources\layout\Main.axml, Res..\values\Strings.xml), and a few other items (e.g. Properties\AndroidManifest.xml, GettingStarted.Xamarin, etc.).

I compile and run it on an attached `BLU Vivo 5 Mini (Android 6.0 - API 23)`. So far so good!

Next come my first attempts at playing with anything .. that surprisingly end badly.

**1.** Renaming MainActivity results in:

`Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{App4.App4/md54bce54f405542800672a5cecd6c84592.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md54bce54f405542800672a5cecd6c84592.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/App4.App4-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/App4.App4-1/lib/arm, /data/app/App4.App4-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Is the name `MainActivity` some kind of a predefined entry-point, similar to C/C++'s `main()`?
I haven't seen any reference to that. But then *what's the point of `[Activity(MainLauncher=true)]` attribute, if not to mark the main/startup activity*?
Fine, for now i rename it back.  Recompile, run .. ok.

**2.** Deleting `GettingStarted.Xamarin` file (*'cause it's just a list of links, present in every project*) seems to result in the same problem!?  That's just an HTML page, so what gives??

Fine, i won't be touching this file anymore.  Close solution, re-create project, run .. ok.

**3.** Modifying Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs to: `[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "1.0.*" )]` (to match the build-version numbering schema for other projects) results in the same problem!..
(Surprisingly, modifying `AssemblyFileVersion` has no bad effect - it runs;  maybe Android side is offended by results of using `*`-wildcard? But why?..)

Fine, i'll forgo all the best hard-learned efforts to keep source code organized and maintainable.
Close solution, re-create project, run .. ok.

**4.** Renaming `Main` layout (to `ActMain` or even `MainActivity` - to match activity name) results in yet another similar startup exception.

"Fool!", says i, and revert back. Recompile, run .. ok. I should learn by now, right?

**What gets me is that code always compiles, all these issues are popping up at run time!?!?**

Fine, i give up, i'm not gonna modify anything that Xamarin or VS generates upfront.  To make the experiment clean even further i restart VS, kill off all the previous projects and create a new one - let's start fresh with a Blank template.

**5.** Going forward the entry-point into the app would be a Log-in "page", so i add some `TextView`, `EditText` and `Button` controls to the `Main.axml`:
[image: AXML Layouts]
Buttons don't do anything yet - code is empty. Compile, run .. so far so good. Lovely!

Now i add a new Activity and give it a name `ActSettings`. Yes, i like Hungarian notation, hate me for that if you want, but it helps me keep my objects organized. But that is besides the point: *at this moment i should be free to name a new class anything i want, shouldn't i*?

Next i create a corresponding layout, and [obviously] name it `ActSettings`.  Slap a few controls into it as well.

Compile, run .. ok.

There was no code linking activities together yet - let's add it:

**6.** Here's the solution and MainActivity.cs code with added action:
[image: MainActivity.cs with btOpts_Click]
I hear Doug Marcaida going: "It *will* compile. But will it **run**?"

**7.** Nope, here's what i get (.NET knows `ActSettings` class pretty well, but not Java!?):
[image: ClassNotFoundException]

```
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867): JNIEnv.FindClass(Type) caught unexpected exception: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/lib/arm, /data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <0fb41b3e3d7346ce92c4a742b20078ff>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00017] in <0fb41b3e3d7346ce92c4a742b20078ff>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x0003d] in <0fb41b3e3d7346ce92c4a742b20078ff>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.Type type) [0x00015] in <0fb41b3e3d7346ce92c4a742b20078ff>:0 
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings
02-02 13:47:11.686 W/monodroid( 5867):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/lib/arm, /data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-02 13:47:11.687 W/monodroid( 5867):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):  ... 13 more
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):      ... 14 more
02-02 13:47:11.688 W/monodroid( 5867):  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActSettings occurred
```

And it doesn't matter, what i call it: `SecondActivity` *does not* work either!

**8.** The closest similar question already asked is [Second activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834141/), but a) it is from 2011, b) there's no accepted answer, c) answers point to `AndroidManifest.xml` file.. Well, here it is:
[image: AndroidManifest.xml]
Notice, that the file in the project doesn't even mention half the stuff!  Yet the generated output has all the activities spelled out perfectly, which only deepens my confusion.

**9.** Another question [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/) is probably closest, but again, it's from 2013 and it's tagged `Java` (not `Android`, `Xamarin` or anything related to phones).
I have absolutely no clue, where is that `classpath`, how and what to set it to, and most importantly *why would Xamarin or VisualStudio-2017 not do that for me properly in the first place*?

I would expect that a modern IDE touting platform support would be properly covering all the bases. Eventually the app would need TCP/UDP communication over WiFi, background / foreground servi-ces, notifications, and what not. But i'm having a fit simply doing "Hello, world!" :o

I tried running (and renaming files and classes!) [ActivityLifecycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/ActivityLifecycle/) example, which launches a second activity, and it works perfectly .. *provided i have not changed any names*. If i do - it fails, but reverting names makes it work again. *I cannot find any reasonable differences between that sample's code and my own, which would explain why Android can't find my second activity*.

What am i doing wrong? Or not doing? Please help!

Comment: I assume you tried rebuilding the solution after renaming the `MainActivity`, because it is not a pre-defined entrypoint. The start-up activity is based on `MainLauncher = true`.

Comment: Can you post what the manifest in the obj/Debug folder looks like right after you change the name and deploy and it errors out.

Comment: Well, thank you! 1) Tried rebuilding from scratch several times, restarting VS and removing entire project folders in-between - to make certain there are no hanging "leftovers". Yesterday was told of uninstalling apps on the device - had hopes for that (maybe stale .apk?), but nope - did not make any difference. 2) The pictured manifest is "current" - to the moment of failure. Sidenote: there're multiple copies of it in subfolders of displayed path (?? another wonder..), but they all have identical content.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this error. What do your Android Build options look like?

Comment: also, what version of vs 2017?

Comment: Thank you guys!! For completeness, VStudio's version is 15.5.4, Xamarin - 4.8.0.757, Xamarin.Android SDK - 8.1.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Renaming MainActivity results in:
>
> Unhandled Exception:
> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{App4.App4/md54bce54f405542800672a5cecd6c84592.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ......

#### This is an issue about Xamarin and it was fixed in newest Visual Studio vesion, it has no business with your code.

You could refer to Jon Douglas's answer : [Xamarin.Android app only finding launcher activity on clean compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425799/xamarin-android-app-only-finding-launcher-activity-on-clean-compile/48427487#48427487)
.

> This issue has been fixed and be included in `Visual Studio 15.5.5` or `Visual Studio 15.6 Preview 3`.
>
> The respective Xamarin.Android version this fix is included in are `Xamarin.Android 8.1.5.0 (Stable)` and `Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.6 (Preview)`

## Solution 1:

Update your Visual Studio to the latest version, Visual Studio 15.5.6 is available now.

## Solution 2:

- Delete your solution bin&obj folder
- Rebuild again

Comment: Thank you!! Solution2 (removing the folders) works. Automating it by adding "del /q $(ProjectDir)\bin" and "del /q $(ProjectDir)\obj" into project's pre-build event .. does NOT, but that's for another Q. So far (to keep things simple) I chose to download and replace `Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll` from BugZilla thread, linked to in Jon Douglas' answer.